# Change the file's name when I push project in the github

Tags: github, push

Hi everyone I have a question about the `git push`

After finish the code, I pushed my project file into my GitHub repository.

But suddenly one of the folder name in the project changed in my GitHub repository

In my local computer the folder name was `ReservaionList`, but in my GitHub repository, the folder name was changed to `reservationList`. So Every time I cloned that file and I had to change that name by myself to avoid errors while I testing.

What happening? Is there anyone who faced the same experience as me?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Windows? Do you have `core.ignoreCase` set?

Comment: @Schwern No, I use Mac. and what is the core.ignoreCase? There are some StackOverflow info who said that but I don't know exactly how to set up

Comment: Mac and Windows are both case-insensitive so `reservationList` and `ReservationList` are the same file. Setting `core.ignoreCase` true tells Git to expect this. Likely your local file is `ReservationList` but someone checked in `reservationList` and Github is honoring the original name. You should be able to check the real filename with `git log --stat` and check if `core.ignoreCase` is set with `git config -l`.